# Sql Server migration from old server to new very slow SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server, database-design, slow-query

Hope someone can assist me. I think I might know what the problem is but this is not really resolving the issue and was wondering if it is even a valid conclusion. I am not a Guru at all with SQL.

Running windows sever standard 2019

OLD Server Specs:

- 32 gigs ddr4 Dimm Ram
- Intel i7-7700 3.6ghz cpu
- 1 socket 4 cores / 8 Threads
- 1T SSD

New Server windows server 2019 date center

- 256 Gig DDR4 dimm Ram
- Xeon E5 2699 v4 2.2ghz cpu
- 2 x sockets 22 x 2 cores =44 /88 Threads                                                    - 4x 1.8T Sas Drives        Raid 5   (backups)
- 5x 1T evo Sata SSD  tried raid5 and raid10        (SQL DAtaBase)
- 2x 1T samsung evo Nvme    Tried mirrored and normal  (Windows install)

Vms was given a lot and the same quantity of ram then old server bur no improvement.

Currently we are running 3 Vms

- vm1 AD-DC
- vm2 SQL-Database and IIS
- vm3 RDS Terminal

Working with 4 x 10 gig datebases since sql express is limited to 10gig.

Storage configuration

- Vm1 AD-DC 1 x V-H drive image stored on (windows drive nvme) 50Gig Storage allocated
- vm2 1 x V-H drive for the os 120GIG and 1 x V-h drive for sql data on the raid 10 and raid 5 tested both Samsung evo drives (2.8T storage allocated)
- Vm3  - RDS Terminal  V-H drive Iso on Sql raid Samsung evo Drive 100gig

The VM storage and Virtual h-drives was changed around to test if it might be the raid controller or a drive which was causing the slow responds on retrieving data from the Database.

The old and new server are setup the same with the 3 vms same V-h drive configuration and drives used but when trying to load the application we use to access the data It takes forever almost 30 seconds longer and all of the actions when loaded in you click and wait 10 seconds on the new server.

Even when all of the VMs and all of the storage are on one physical drive no performance difference.

All of the VMS and Host is set to best performance and all of the drivers are installed as per previous discussions.

Tried giving all of the VMs double the memory and processors even the SQL VM No difference.

**Theory** My Suspicion If it is valid and that is what i want to know is Since SQL Express is limited to 1 gig of memory and  4 processors it does not matter if i give it more but the clock speed between the 2 servers are much different so comparing 4x 2.2ghz with 4 x 3.7ghz The old server will be faster on the SQL EXPRESS in till we upgrade it to the full version where i can assign more processors?

Hope this make sense and that i did not leave anything out but if someone can give some advice it will be greatly appreciated.

Is the Theory valid?

Comment: That's a lot of fancy hardware for an Express edition. Please provide SQL Server version and edition for both old and new servers. Anything else running on these servers? What is the actual server cofiguration? You seem to be talking about the new server as physical, but then start mentioning VMS, I assume Virtual Machines. Also it sounds like you built completely new envirnment for the whole application. Please clarify this, otherwise it's hard to reason about what your actual problem is. Could very well be outside SQL Server.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply we are looking at upgrading soon to the standard edition but for now still stuck on sql express. We are currently running  SQL Express 2014. The virtual machines were setup on the dell 730xd since on the old server there was only 1 vm which was handling ad-dc,rds server,iis,and sql we then split it up to be 3 separate vms on the new dell server . First i though ok things changed now so that is the issue but then i reverted back and exported this 3 vms which was configured on the dell to the old server exactly the same and puff no problem runs fine no problems.

Comment: same version same database same settings it is an exact replica of the old server config which we moved between the 2 servers the only difference between the two are the hardware. Which i tried to eliminate the drives so I installed all 3 Virtual machines on 1 ssd on new and old server to test the performance and again on the old server runs fine but on the new dell server just the sql loading in and clicking on the tabs takes very long. The over all performance of the vm is great cpu is not even working memory is low. it is very weird.

Comment: I would check CPU and I/O usage and run sp_WhoIsActive when you experience slowdowns. This should give you a hint, if it is indeed the SQL Server. If you can compare it to the old server, even better

Comment: Very unlikely a hardware issue. Run [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) while the slowest query on the new server is running and save the results. Also, manually run that slow query in SSMS on both the new server and old server with the [actual execution plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver16) enabled. Right click the plan, then click "View Execution Plan XML" and then paste it into [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan). Add all of that info to your Post, for further help.

Comment: thanks a lot I will do that.

Comment: You tagged your question 'mysql' but I don't see any relevance to MySQL. Is that tag misplaced?

Comment: Yes sorry about that misplaced will try to remove. when running sp_whoisactive and following the instructions will that cause disruption or can i do the tests and so forth while  users are using the database?

Comment: @Eduard "*when running sp_whoisactive and following the instructions will that cause disruption or can i do the tests and so forth while users are using the database?*" - [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) is pretty lightweight and *usually* ok to run once or twice in the middle of a live workload. Getting a querv's actual execution plan is also ok. The actual running of the slow query itself may or may not impact server performance though, depending on how busy your server, and what that query is doing. That's not something any of us would know the answer to, and you'd have to decide.